# How can I Provide Permissions to a PHP Docker Image and Host VOLUME?

Tags: php, docker, fedora

I'm working with the official PHP docker image and I'm trying to add a host path as a VOLUME. My intent is for local development.

My Dockerfile is pretty basic:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
VOLUME ["/var/www/html/"]
```

Then in my `docker run` command I'm just adding the `-v` flag:

```
$ docker run -d -v ~/Workspace/website/:/var/www/html/ ...
```

However, I get a 403 after start. If I execute a bash entry I can see /var/www/html is permission denied. I think this has to do with the "alien" user/group for the guest.

Log:

> [Tue Jan 26 00:29:38.182727 2016] [core:error] [pid 10] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.5.1:37996] AH00035: access to /index.php denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/index.php') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
>   192.168.5.1 - - [26/Jan/2016:00:29:38 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 446 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

Stat:

```
# stat html/
File: 'html/'
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 3148160     Links: 26
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1000/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2016-01-25 23:17:57.096095138 +0000
Modify: 2016-01-26 00:28:10.274181924 +0000
Change: 2016-01-26 00:28:10.274181924 +0000
```

**UPDATE**

I took Geany's suggestion and change the gid of the www-data group to 1000 to match the gid of the host's path.

```
$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
$ groupmod -g 1000 www-data
$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=1000(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
$ stat html/
File: 'html/'
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 3148160     Links: 26
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1000/ www-data)
Access: 2016-01-25 23:17:57.096095138 +0000
Modify: 2016-01-26 00:28:10.274181924 +0000
Change: 2016-01-26 00:28:10.274181924 +0000
```

However, this still did not fix the permissions. I even changed the uid.

**UPDATE #2**

I just confirmed this works flawlessly on OS X. I was originally trying to make it work on Fedora 23.

Comment: It's for sure a permissions problem. However, I can't pinpoint it exactly given the information above. That said, you're definitely on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You should check user and group of apache worker processes and chown source directory.
Another way is change gid and uid of apache worker user.

Comment: The apache process is ran by a worker named www-data. I'll try changing the gid.

Comment: I use Fedora 23 also and set up my php application with multiple containers, nginx + php-fpm.
In host I have a user john with uid/gid 1000/1000
In nginx container I changed nginx uid/gid to 1000/1000, `groupmod -g 1000 nginx` and `usermod -u 1000 nginx`.
In php-fpm container I remove default apache user and add nginx user with uid/gid 1000/1000, `userdel apache`, `groupadd -g 1000 nginx`, `useradd -u 1000 -g 1000 nginx`
Everything works perfect! :)

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache as web server?

Comment: I use nginx but I think apache is the same. You have to make sure that webserver and php process have permission to access source code.